# How to set connection using Apache Spark Sql as a database in .Net Core?

Tags: .net, apache-spark-sql

public string ConnectionString
{
get
{
var dbInfo = DBInfo as SparkDBInfo;
var builder = new ***(ConnectionStringofSpark)***
{
Database = dbInfo.Database,
Host = dbInfo.Server
};
if (dbInfo.Port > 0)
{
builder.Port = dbInfo.Port;
}
else
{
builder.Port = xxxx;
}
builder.IntegratedSecurity = dbInfo.SSPI;

```
            if (!dbInfo.SSPI)
            {
                builder.Username = dbInfo.Username;
                builder.Password = dbInfo.Password;
            }

            return builder.ConnectionString;
        }
    }
```

***(ConnectionStringofSpark)*** under this name i want to write the connection function that Spark has, but i am not able to find it. So it has to be like in postgres, or in sql. Does exists for spark any function for the connection with spark sql database (with itself as a database and not with other providers)?